# passing hash in subroutines

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

I have made a simple perl script for printing hash key/value pairs through subroutine

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

#passing hash to a subroutine

sub printhash{

           my (%hash) = @_;

           foreach my $key (keys %hash){

                    my $value = $hash{$key};

                    print "$key : $value\n ";

          }

}

%hash = {'name' => 'devendra', 'age' => 21};

printhash(%hash);
```

**Expected Output:**

name : devendra

age : 21

**Ouput:**

HASH(0x1be0e78) :

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
%hash = {'name' => 'devendra', 'age' => 21};
```

is attempting to assign an anonymous hash reference to a hash. What you really mean is

```
%hash = ('name' => 'devendra', 'age' => 21);
```

If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` you would have seen the message

> Reference found where even-sized list expected

cluing you in to the problem. Always use them!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning passing by reference as an optiom